# postgresql timezone conversion 'EST' != '-05'

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am running PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu and my time zone is set to 'UTC'.

Does anyone know why the results of the following `SELECT` statements are different?

A)

```
SELECT timezone('EST', '2017-12-21');
    timezone       
---------------------
2017-12-20 19:00:00
```

B)

```
SELECT timezone('-05', '2017-12-21');
      timezone       
---------------------
2017-12-21 05:00:00
```

According to the `pg_timezone_names` table `-05` should have the same offset as `EST`... Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html

> The view pg_timezone_names provides a list of time zone names that are
>   recognized by SET TIMEZONE

and further:

> utc_offset    interval    Offset from UTC (positive means east of Greenwich)

when you `set timezone to 'EST'` - you declare that your client is in EST time zone, thus returned time will be adjusted for your tz:

```
t=# select '2017-12-21'::timestamptz;
      timestamptz
------------------------
 2017-12-21 00:00:00-05
(1 row)
```

the interval match utc_offset from `pg_timezone_names` and isequal `-05`, so it works as expected. (indeed in EST will be 5 hours less then UTC) same result if you `set timezone to '-05'`.

Both `-05` and `EST` give same result for `SET TIMEZONE` as described in docs.

Now you answer reconciles with docs on using `interval`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT

> In these expressions, the desired time zone zone can be specified
>   either as a text string (e.g., 'PST') or as an interval (e.g.,
>   INTERVAL '-08:00').

following these rules it works as well:

```
t=# select '2017-12-21'::timestamptz at time zone 'EST';
      timezone
---------------------
 2017-12-20 19:00:00
(1 row)

t=# select '2017-12-21'::timestamptz at time zone interval '-05:00';
      timezone
---------------------
 2017-12-20 19:00:00
(1 row)
```

but further, docs say:

> In the text case, a time zone name can be specified in any of the ways
>   described in Section 8.5.3.

which is https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES

> PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms:
>
> - recognized time zone names are listed in the pg_timezone_names
> - recognized abbreviations are listed in the pg_timezone_abbrevs
> - POSIX-style time zone specifications of the form STDoffset or STDoffsetDST

(formatting mine)

and lastly:

> One should be wary that the POSIX-style time zone feature can lead to
>   silently accepting bogus input...Another issue to keep in mind is that
>   in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations **west**
>   of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601
>   convention that positive timezone offsets are **east** of Greenwich.

### TL;DR

**So in short** - when you define '-05' as text (not interval) input for `timezone()` function or `AT TIME ZONE` directive (effectively same) Postgres thinks this is an attempt to use POSIX style time zone **and thus inverts sign**, thus you get "opposite" result...

a simple demonstration of this documented inversion:

```
t=# select '2017-12-21'::timestamptz at time zone '05';
      timezone
---------------------
 2017-12-20 19:00:00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I found an answer to my own question:

According to the PostgreSQL docs, section 9.9.3 at the following link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html

> In these expressions, the desired time zone zone can be specified either as a text string (e.g., 'PST') or as an interval (e.g., INTERVAL '-08:00'). In the text case, a time zone name can be specified in any of the ways described in Section 8.5.3.

So using the `INTERVAL` syntax, the following appears to work:

```
SELECT timezone(INTERVAL '-05:00', '2017-12-21');
      timezone       
---------------------
2017-12-20 19:00:00
```

I think it is still curious, what exactly `SELECT timezone('-05', '2017-12-21');` means, as the following also provides the expected result (with the addition of a TZ offset):

```
SELECT timezone('-05', '2017-12-21'::timestamp);
        timezone        
------------------------
2017-12-20 19:00:00+00
```